# Regex on PageSource in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I am trying to create basic extension that finds a simple code that is often referenced in different pages in source (inside script tags, inside html classes etc).

Is there a way to run regex over the source code of a page inside?

Specicially, I have tried the following without success:

```
var code = document.innerHtml.match(/(b|cd)ef/)[0]
```

Comment: `'(b|cd)ef'` should be `/(b|cd)ef/`

Comment: Thanks, have updated above but still doesnt work

Comment: What is the input, what you expect to match and what is the current match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you can do

```js
const matchingCode = /.*croiss.*\s*/.exec(document.querySelector('#code').innerText, 'gmi');

console.log(matchingCode);
```

```html
<div id="code">
  <div>
    J'aime les croissants
  </div>

  <div>
    Moi j'aime les endives
  </div>
</div>
```